# Can ogr2ogr write data to a file geodatabase feature dataset?

Tags: gdal, ogr2ogr, file-geodatabase, osgeo4w

I am dumping postgis tables into a file geodatabase and it works great--the result is a  file geodatabase full of featureclasses.

But is it possible to write these featureclasses into feature datasets (they are the same spatial reference):

[image: e]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**[Edited]**

If your feature classes are saved as *.shp, you could try:

```
ogr2ogr -f "FileGDB" mygdb.gdb ~/PathTo/MyFeatureClass.shp -lco FEATURE_DATASET=my_features
```

However, since you are exporting from PostGIS another approach could be something like this:

```
ogr2ogr -f "FileGDB" mygdb.gdb PG:"host=my_host user=my_user_name dbname=my_db_name password=my_password" -sql "SELECT gid, name, the_geom from fd_line_Test" -lco FEATURE_DATASET=my_features
```

Alternatively, you can just point the PostGIS tables:

```
ogr2ogr -f "FileGDB" mygdb.gdb PG:"host=my_host user=my_user_name dbname=my_db_name password=my_password" fd_lines_test fd_poly_test fd_pt_test -lco FEATURE_DATASET=my_features
```

Simlliar to the last one will be if you export and import from GeoDatabase:

```
ogr2ogr -f "FileGDB" mygdb.gdb IdentityTest.gdb fd_lines_test fd_poly_test fd_pt_test -lco FEATURE_DATASET=my_features
```

[ESRI File Geodatabase (FileGDB) Layer Creation Options](http://www.gdal.org/drv_filegdb.html)

Comment: The question is asking about feature dataset.

Comment: There's a `-lco FEATURE_DATASET=my_featurs` layer creation option for [FileGDB](http://www.gdal.org/drv_filegdb.html)

Comment: `-lco FEATURE_DATASET`....that's what I was looking for. That's so much easier than the way I was hacking it!

Comment: Hi @Hristo Tomov, I'm trying to use the code you provided __ ogr2ogr -f "FileGDB" mygdb.gdb ~/PathTo/MyFeatureClass.shp -lco FEATURE_DATASET=my_features
__ to convert a shapefile to a gbd feature class but I get errors like: unable to find driver 'filegdb'. any help is appreciated.

Comment: FileGDB is not included in ogr as default. You need to download/install file gdb .dll separately using eg. osgeo